# D3v6 convex hull examples

Tags: d3.js

Recently I noticed the convex hull possibilities in D3. For example this one:

```js
var w = 960,
    h = 500,
    fill = d3.scale.category10(),
    nodes = d3.range(9).map(Object);

var groups = d3.nest().key(function(d) { return d & 3; }).entries(nodes);

var groupPath = function(d) {
    var fakePoints = [];
    if (d.values.length == 2)
    {
        //[dx, dy] is the direction vector of the line
        var dx = d.values[1].x - d.values[0].x;
        var dy = d.values[1].y - d.values[0].y;

        //scale it to something very small
        dx *= 0.00001; dy *= 0.00001;

        //orthogonal directions to a 2D vector [dx, dy] are [dy, -dx] and [-dy, dx]
        //take the midpoint [mx, my] of the line and translate it in both directions
        var mx = (d.values[0].x + d.values[1].x) * 0.5;
        var my = (d.values[0].y + d.values[1].y) * 0.5;
        fakePoints = [ [mx + dy, my - dx],
                      [mx - dy, my + dx]];
        //the two additional points will be sufficient for the convex hull algorithm
    }

    //do not forget to append the fakePoints to the input data
    return "M" + 
        d3.geom.hull(d.values.map(function(i) { return [i.x, i.y]; })
                     .concat(fakePoints))
        .join("L") 
        + "Z";
}

var groupFill = function(d, i) { return fill(i & 3); };

var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links([])
    .size([w, h])
    .start();

var node = vis.selectAll("circle.node")
    .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("r", 8)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i & 3); })
    .style("stroke", function(d, i) { return d3.rgb(fill(i & 3)).darker(2); })
    .style("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .call(force.drag);

vis.style("opacity", 1e-6)
  .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .style("opacity", 1);

force.on("tick", function(e) {

  // Push different nodes in different directions for clustering.
  var k = 6 * e.alpha;
  nodes.forEach(function(o, i) {
    o.x += i & 2 ? k : -k;
    o.y += i & 1 ? k : -k;
  });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

  vis.selectAll("path")
    .data(groups)
      .attr("d", groupPath)
    .enter().insert("path", "circle")
      .style("fill", groupFill)
      .style("stroke", groupFill)
      .style("stroke-width", 40)
      .style("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .style("opacity", .2)
      .attr("d", groupPath);
});
```

```html
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Unfortunately its version 3 and I am searching for similar layouts made with version 6. I tried to adapt the code but most of functions changed completely, which makes it hard to adapt snippets.

In case somebody stumpled over similar D3v6 snippets, I would be glad.

**UPDATE:**

In addition I found this convex hull example, which use version 4. Still, both version require the `d3.nest()` functions. I was building a version 6 prototyp for `d3.group() / d3.groups()` testing, to receive the same output as `d3.nest()`. Unfortunately without success. Below the version 4 hull example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>D3v4 hull</title>
    <!-- d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
    <!-- d3.js Scale Chromatic plugin -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        path.link {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #666;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        marker#resource {
            fill: red;
        }

        path.link.resource {
            /* stroke: green; */
        }

        path.link.property {
            stroke-dasharray: 0, 2 1;
        }

        circle {
            opacity: 1;
            stroke: #333;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        text {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        text.shadow {
            stroke: #fff;
            stroke-width: 3px;
            stroke-opacity: .8;
        }

        .nodes {
            opacity: 1;
        }

    </style>

<body>
    <div id="canvas"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = {
            'nodes': [{
                'id': 'A',
                'label': 'A',
                'type': 'resource',
                'size': 40,
                'group': 'a',
            }, {
                'id': 'B',
                'label': 'B',
                'type': 'resource',
                'size': 40,
                'group': 'a'
            }, {
                'id': 'C',
                'label': 'C',
                'type': 'resource',
                'size': 40,
                'group': 'x',
            }, {
                'id': 'D',
                'label': 'D',
                'type': 'resource',
                'size': 40,
                'group': 'x'
            }, {
                'id': 'E',
                'label': 'E',
                'type': 'resource',
                'size': 40,
                'group': 'x'
            }, {
                'id': 'F',
                'label': 'F',
                'type': 'resource',
                'size': 40,
                'group': 'a'
            }, {
                'id': 'Q',
                'label': 'Q',
                'type': 'resource',
                'size': 40,
                'group': 'q'
            }, {
                'id': 'W',
                'label': 'Wjk',
                'type': 'resource',
                'size': 40,
                'group': 'q'
            }, {
                'id': 'Z',
                'label': 'Z',
                'type': 'resource',
                'size': 40,
                'group': 'q'
            }],
            'links': [{
                'source': 'E',
                'target': 'F',
                'type': 'resource',
                'distance': 100,
                'strength': 1
            }, {
                'source': 'A',
                'target': 'F',
                'type': 'resource',
                'distance': 100,
                'strength': 1
            }, {
                'source': 'A',
                'target': 'C',
                'type': 'resource',
                'distance': 100,
                'strength': 1
            }, {
                'source': 'Q',
                'target': 'F',
                'type': 'resource',
                'distance': 100,
                'strength': 1
            }, {
                'source': 'Q',
                'target': 'E',
                'type': 'resource',
                'distance': 100,
                'strength': 1
            }, {
                'source': 'W',
                'target': 'Q',
                'type': 'resource',
                'distance': 100,
                'strength': 1
            }]
        };

        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var w = canvas.clientWidth, h = canvas.clientHeight;
        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeSet3);
        var svg = d3.select(canvas).append('svg')
            .attr('width', w)
            .attr('height', h);
        var rectWidth = 80,
            rectHeight = 30;
        var markerWidth = 10,
            markerHeight = 6,
            cRadius = 180, // play with the cRadius value
            refX = 70, //refX = cRadius + markerWidth,
            refY = 0, //refY = -Math.sqrt(cRadius),
            drSub = cRadius + refY;

        var tocolor = "fill";
        var towhite = "stroke";
        if (outline) {
            tocolor = "stroke"
            towhite = "fill"
        }

        var focus_node = null, highlight_node = null;

        var highlight_color = "blue";
        var highlight_trans = 0.1;
        var outline = false;
        var default_node_color = "#ccc";
        //var default_node_color = "rgb(3,190,100)";
        var default_link_color = "#888";

        var g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "viz");
        var net, convexHull, genCH, linkElements, nodeElements, textElements, circle, simulation, linkForce;

        var expand = {};

        var linkedByIndex = {};
        data.links.forEach(function (d) {
            linkedByIndex[d.source + "," + d.target] = true;
        });
        function isConnected(a, b) {
            return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index] || a.index == b.index;
        }
        

        var groupFill = function (d, i) { return color(d.key); };

        function getGroup(n) { return n.group; }

        function network(data, prev, cekGroup, expand) {
            var cnode, groupIndex, mappedNodes = [], mappedLinks = [], clink, tempN, tempL = [], newNodes = [], soIn, taIn, lw = 0, newLinks = [];
            if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(expand).length == 0) {
                for (var j = 0; j < data.nodes.length; j++) {
                    groupIndex = cekGroup(data.nodes[j]);
                    expand[groupIndex] = true;
                }
                nodes = data.nodes;
                links = data.links;
            } else {
                for (var k = 0; k < data.nodes.length; k++) {
                    cnode = data.nodes[k];
                    groupIndex = cekGroup(cnode);
                    if (expand[groupIndex]) {
                        mappedNodes.push(cnode);
                        //if expand true, nodes condition expand
                    } else {
                        if (!newNodes[groupIndex]) {
                            tempN = {
                                'id': groupIndex,
                                'label': 'domain ' + groupIndex,
                                'type': 'resource',
                                'size': 30,
                                'group': groupIndex
                            };
                            newNodes[groupIndex] = tempN;
                            mappedNodes.push(tempN);
                        }
                        // if expand false, nodes condition collapse
                    }
                    //iterate through all data.nodes
                }


                for (var x = 0; x < data.links.length; x++) {
                    clink = data.links[x];
                    soIn = cekGroup(clink.source);
                    taIn = cekGroup(clink.target);
                    tempL = {};
                    // if(!expand[soIn] && expand[taIn]) {
                    //   tempL.source = newNodes[soIn];
                    // }

                    if (expand[soIn] && expand[taIn]) {
                        //console.log('if1');
                        //tempL=clink;
                        soIn = clink.source.id;
                        taIn = clink.target.id;
                    } else if (!expand[soIn] && expand[taIn]) {
                        //console.log('if2');
                        //tempL.source = newNodes[soIn];
                        soIn = soIn;
                        taIn = clink.target.id;
                    } else if (expand[soIn] && !expand[taIn]) {
                        //console.log('if3');
                        //tempL.target = newNodes[taIn];
                        taIn = taIn;
                        soIn = clink.source.id;
                    } else if (!expand[soIn] && !expand[taIn]) {
                        //console.log('if4');
                        //tempL=null;
                        if (soIn == taIn) { soIn = ''; taIn = ''; }
                    }
                    if (soIn != '' && taIn != '') {
                        tempL = {
                            'source': soIn,
                            'target': taIn,
                            'type': clink.type,
                            'distance': 50,
                            'strength': 1
                        }
                        mappedLinks.push(tempL);
                    }
                }
                nodes = mappedNodes;
                links = mappedLinks;
                // endof if expand not empty
            }

            return { nodes: nodes, links: links };
        }
    
        var offset = 0, groups, groupPath;
        function init() {
            if (simulation) {
                linkElements.remove();
                nodeElements.remove();
                genCH.remove();
                convexHull.remove();
                textElements.remove();
            }
            net = network(data, net, getGroup, expand);
            groups = d3.nest().key(function (d) { return d.group; }).entries(net.nodes);
            console.log(groups)
            
            groupPath = function (d) {
                var txt;
                if (d.values.length == 1) {
                    return "M0,0L0,0L0,0Z";
                } else {
                    return "M" +
                        d3.polygonHull(d.values.map(function (i) { return [i.x + offset, i.y + offset]; }))
                            .join("L")
                        + "Z";
                }

            };
            convexHull = g.append('g').attr('class', 'hull');
            // simulation setup with all forces
            linkForce = d3
                .forceLink()
                .id(function (link) { return link.id })
                .strength(function (link) { return 0.2 })

            var inpos = [], counterX = 1, inposY = [], counterY = 1;
            simulation = d3
                .forceSimulation()
                .force('link', d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
        return d.id;
    }).distance(150))
                .force('forceX', d3.forceX(function (d) {
                    if (inpos[d.group]) {
                        
                        return inpos[d.group];
                    } else {
                        inpos[d.group] = w / counterX;
                        
                        counterX++;
                        return inpos[d.group];
                    }
                }))
                .force('forceY', d3.forceY(function (d) {
                    if (inposY[d.group]) {
                        
                        return inposY[d.group];
                    } else {
                        inposY[d.group] = h / (Math.random() * (d.group.length - 0 + 1) + 1);
                        
                        return inposY[d.group];
                    }
                }))
                .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-500))
                .force('center', d3.forceCenter(w / 2, h / 2))
                .force("gravity", d3.forceManyBody(50));

            linkElements = g.append('g').attr('class', 'links').selectAll('path').data(net.links).enter().append('path')
                .attr('class', function (d) { return 'link ' + d.type; })
                

            nodeElements = g.append('g').attr('class', 'nodes').selectAll('.node')
                .data(net.nodes)
                .enter().append('g')
                .attr('class', 'node');
            // .append('circle')
            // .attr("r", cRadius)
            // .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(d.group);});
            circle = nodeElements.filter(function (d) { return d.type == 'resource'; }).append('circle')
                .attr('class', 'circle')
                .attr("r", function (d) { return d.size; })
                .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.group); });

            nodeElements.call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended));

            textElements = g.append("g")
                .attr("class", "texts")
                .selectAll("text")
                .data(net.nodes)
                .enter().append('text')
                .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
                .append('tspan')
                .text(function (node) { return node.label });

            simulation.nodes(net.nodes).on('tick', () => {
                genCH = convexHull.selectAll("path")
                    .data(groups)
                    .attr("d", groupPath)
                    .enter().insert("path", "circle")
                    .style("fill", groupFill)
                    .style("stroke", groupFill)
                    .style("stroke-width", 140)
                    .style("stroke-linejoin", "round")
                    .style("opacity", .5)
                    .on('click', function (d) {
                        expand[d.key] = false;
                        init();
                    })
                    .attr("d", groupPath);

                nodeElements
                    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
                // .attr('x', function (node) { console.log(node); return node.x })
                // .attr('y', function (node) { return node.y })
                textElements
                    .attr('x', function (node) { return node.x })
                    .attr('y', function (node) { return node.y })
                linkElements
                    .attr('d', function (d) {
                        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
                            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                    

                        var val = 'M' + d.source.x + ',' + d.source.y + 'A' + (dr - drSub) + ',' + (dr - drSub) + ' 0 0,1 ' + d.target.x + ',' + d.target.y;

                        var val2 = 'M' + d.source.x + ',' + d.source.y + 'L' + (d.target.x) + ',' + (d.target.y);
                        if (d.type == 'resource') return val2;
                        else return val1;
                    });
            })

            nodeElements.on("mouseover", function (d) {
                set_highlight(d);
            })
                .on("mousedown", function (d) {
                    d3.event.stopPropagation();
                    focus_node = d;
                
                    set_focus(d)
                    if (highlight_node === null) set_highlight(d)

                }).on("mouseout", function (d) {
                    exit_highlight();

                }).on("click", function (d) {
                    d3.event.stopPropagation();
                
                    setExpand(d);
                });

            simulation.force("link").links(net.links).distance(function (d) {
                if (d.source.group == d.target.group) return 85;
                else return 180;
                // if(d.type=='resource') return 300;
                // else return 150;
                // return d.distance;
            });

            function setExpand(d) {
                expand[d.id] = !expand[d.id];
                init();
            }

            function exit_highlight() {
                highlight_node = null;
                if (focus_node === null) {
                    svg.style("cursor", "move");
                    if (highlight_color != "white") {
                        circle.style(towhite, "white");
                        linkElements.style("stroke", function (o) { return (isNumber(o.score) && o.score >= 0) ? color(o.score) : default_link_color });
                    }

                }
            }

            function set_focus(d) {
                if (highlight_trans < 1) {
                    circle.style("opacity", function (o) {
                        return isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : highlight_trans;
                    });

                    linkElements.style("opacity", function (o) {
                        return o.source.index == d.index || o.target.index == d.index ? 1 : highlight_trans;
                    });
                }
            }

            function set_highlight(d) {

                svg.style("cursor", "pointer");
                // circle.style('opacity',0.7);
                if (focus_node !== null) d = focus_node;
                highlight_node = d;

                if (highlight_color != "white") {
                    circle.style(towhite, function (o) {
                        return isConnected(d, o) ? highlight_color : "white";
                    });
                    //             linkElements.style("stroke", function(o) {
                    //            return o.source.index == d.index || o.target.index == d.index ? highlight_color : ((isNumber(o.score) && o.score>=0)?color(o.score):default_link_color);
                    // });
                }
            }

            function dragstarted(d) {
                if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
                d.fx = d.x;
                d.fy = d.y;
            }

            function dragged(d) {
                d.fx = d3.event.x;
                d.fy = d3.event.y;
            }

            function dragended(d) {
                if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
                d.fx = null;
                d.fy = null;
            }
            // endof init()
        }

        init();
        //add zoom capabilities
        var zoom_handler = d3.zoom()
            .on("zoom", zoom_actions);

        zoom_handler(svg);
        function zoom_actions() {
            g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
        }

        function isNumber(n) {
            return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The whole concept of the force simulation is very different in V6. You can fix some errors like `d3.scale.category10` but it still will not work (I tried)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good research finding a v4 version of that force directed graph with convex hull groupings.

To convert to v6 is just a couple more steps:

As you know, replace `d3.nest` with `d3.groups` - but the missing step is to convert the output of `d3.groups` from an array of arrays to an array of objects. So this:

```
groups = d3.groups(
  net.nodes, 
  d => d.group
).map(x => ({key: x[0], values: x[1]}));
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
groups = d3.nest()
  .key(function (d) { return d.group; })
  .entries(net.nodes);
```

Then go through all the event handlers and update them so `event` is passed as an argument and drop the `d3.` wherevere you see `d3.event`.

This seems to work pretty well:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>D3v4 hull</title>
    <!-- d3.js framework 
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- d3.js Scale Chromatic plugin -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        path.link {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #666;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        marker#resource {
            fill: red;
        }

        path.link.resource {
            /* stroke: green; */
        }

        path.link.property {
            stroke-dasharray: 0, 2 1;
        }

        circle {
            opacity: 1;
            stroke: #333;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }

        text {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        text.shadow {
            stroke: #fff;
            stroke-width: 3px;
            stroke-opacity: .8;
        }

        .nodes {
            opacity: 1;
        }

    </style>

<body>
    <div id="canvas"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = {
            'nodes': [{
                'id': 'A',
                'label': 'A',
                'type': 'resource',
                'size': 40,
                'group': 'a',
            }, {
                'id': 'B',
                'label': 'B',
                'type': 'resource',
                'size': 40,
                'group': 'a'
            }, {
                'id': 'C',
                'label': 'C',
                'type': 'resource',
                'size': 40,
                'group': 'x',
            }, {
                'id': 'D',
                'label': 'D',
                'type': 'resource',
                'size': 40,
                'group': 'x'
            }, {
                'id': 'E',
                'label': 'E',
                'type': 'resource',
                'size': 40,
                'group': 'x'
            }, {
                'id': 'F',
                'label': 'F',
                'type': 'resource',
                'size': 40,
                'group': 'a'
            }, {
                'id': 'Q',
                'label': 'Q',
                'type': 'resource',
                'size': 40,
                'group': 'q'
            }, {
                'id': 'W',
                'label': 'Wjk',
                'type': 'resource',
                'size': 40,
                'group': 'q'
            }, {
                'id': 'Z',
                'label': 'Z',
                'type': 'resource',
                'size': 40,
                'group': 'q'
            }],
            'links': [{
                'source': 'E',
                'target': 'F',
                'type': 'resource',
                'distance': 100,
                'strength': 1
            }, {
                'source': 'A',
                'target': 'F',
                'type': 'resource',
                'distance': 100,
                'strength': 1
            }, {
                'source': 'A',
                'target': 'C',
                'type': 'resource',
                'distance': 100,
                'strength': 1
            }, {
                'source': 'Q',
                'target': 'F',
                'type': 'resource',
                'distance': 100,
                'strength': 1
            }, {
                'source': 'Q',
                'target': 'E',
                'type': 'resource',
                'distance': 100,
                'strength': 1
            }, {
                'source': 'W',
                'target': 'Q',
                'type': 'resource',
                'distance': 100,
                'strength': 1
            }]
        };

        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var w = canvas.clientWidth, h = canvas.clientHeight;
        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeSet3);
        var svg = d3.select(canvas).append('svg')
            .attr('width', w)
            .attr('height', h);
        var rectWidth = 80,
            rectHeight = 30;
        var markerWidth = 10,
            markerHeight = 6,
            cRadius = 180, // play with the cRadius value
            refX = 70, //refX = cRadius + markerWidth,
            refY = 0, //refY = -Math.sqrt(cRadius),
            drSub = cRadius + refY;

        var tocolor = "fill";
        var towhite = "stroke";
        if (outline) {
            tocolor = "stroke"
            towhite = "fill"
        }

        var focus_node = null, highlight_node = null;

        var highlight_color = "blue";
        var highlight_trans = 0.1;
        var outline = false;
        var default_node_color = "#ccc";
        //var default_node_color = "rgb(3,190,100)";
        var default_link_color = "#888";

        var g = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "viz");
        var net, convexHull, genCH, linkElements, nodeElements, textElements, circle, simulation, linkForce;

        var expand = {};

        var linkedByIndex = {};
        data.links.forEach(function (d) {
            linkedByIndex[d.source + "," + d.target] = true;
        });
        function isConnected(a, b) {
            return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index] || a.index == b.index;
        }
        

        var groupFill = function (d, i) { return color(d.key); };

        function getGroup(n) { return n.group; }

        function network(data, prev, cekGroup, expand) {
            var cnode, groupIndex, mappedNodes = [], mappedLinks = [], clink, tempN, tempL = [], newNodes = [], soIn, taIn, lw = 0, newLinks = [];
            if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(expand).length == 0) {
                for (var j = 0; j < data.nodes.length; j++) {
                    groupIndex = cekGroup(data.nodes[j]);
                    expand[groupIndex] = true;
                }
                nodes = data.nodes;
                links = data.links;
            } else {
                for (var k = 0; k < data.nodes.length; k++) {
                    cnode = data.nodes[k];
                    groupIndex = cekGroup(cnode);
                    if (expand[groupIndex]) {
                        mappedNodes.push(cnode);
                        //if expand true, nodes condition expand
                    } else {
                        if (!newNodes[groupIndex]) {
                            tempN = {
                                'id': groupIndex,
                                'label': 'domain ' + groupIndex,
                                'type': 'resource',
                                'size': 30,
                                'group': groupIndex
                            };
                            newNodes[groupIndex] = tempN;
                            mappedNodes.push(tempN);
                        }
                        // if expand false, nodes condition collapse
                    }
                    //iterate through all data.nodes
                }


                for (var x = 0; x < data.links.length; x++) {
                    clink = data.links[x];
                    soIn = cekGroup(clink.source);
                    taIn = cekGroup(clink.target);
                    tempL = {};
                    // if(!expand[soIn] && expand[taIn]) {
                    //   tempL.source = newNodes[soIn];
                    // }

                    if (expand[soIn] && expand[taIn]) {
                        //console.log('if1');
                        //tempL=clink;
                        soIn = clink.source.id;
                        taIn = clink.target.id;
                    } else if (!expand[soIn] && expand[taIn]) {
                        //console.log('if2');
                        //tempL.source = newNodes[soIn];
                        soIn = soIn;
                        taIn = clink.target.id;
                    } else if (expand[soIn] && !expand[taIn]) {
                        //console.log('if3');
                        //tempL.target = newNodes[taIn];
                        taIn = taIn;
                        soIn = clink.source.id;
                    } else if (!expand[soIn] && !expand[taIn]) {
                        //console.log('if4');
                        //tempL=null;
                        if (soIn == taIn) { soIn = ''; taIn = ''; }
                    }
                    if (soIn != '' && taIn != '') {
                        tempL = {
                            'source': soIn,
                            'target': taIn,
                            'type': clink.type,
                            'distance': 50,
                            'strength': 1
                        }
                        mappedLinks.push(tempL);
                    }
                }
                nodes = mappedNodes;
                links = mappedLinks;
                // endof if expand not empty
            }

            return { nodes: nodes, links: links };
        }
    
        var offset = 0, groups, groupPath;
        function init() {
            if (simulation) {
                linkElements.remove();
                nodeElements.remove();
                genCH.remove();
                convexHull.remove();
                textElements.remove();
            }
            net = network(data, net, getGroup, expand);
            //groups = d3.nest().key(function (d) { return d.group; }).entries(net.nodes);
            groups = d3.groups(net.nodes, d => d.group).map(x => ({key: x[0], values: x[1]}));
            //console.log(groups)
            
            groupPath = function (d) {
                var txt;
                if (d.values.length == 1) {
                    return "M0,0L0,0L0,0Z";
                } else {
                    return "M" +
                        d3.polygonHull(d.values.map(function (i) { return [i.x + offset, i.y + offset]; }))
                            .join("L")
                        + "Z";
                }

            };
            convexHull = g.append('g').attr('class', 'hull');
            // simulation setup with all forces
            linkForce = d3
                .forceLink()
                .id(function (link) { return link.id })
                .strength(function (link) { return 0.2 })

            var inpos = [], counterX = 1, inposY = [], counterY = 1;
            simulation = d3
                .forceSimulation()
                .force('link', d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {
        return d.id;
    }).distance(150))
                .force('forceX', d3.forceX(function (d) {
                    if (inpos[d.group]) {
                        
                        return inpos[d.group];
                    } else {
                        inpos[d.group] = w / counterX;
                        
                        counterX++;
                        return inpos[d.group];
                    }
                }))
                .force('forceY', d3.forceY(function (d) {
                    if (inposY[d.group]) {
                        
                        return inposY[d.group];
                    } else {
                        inposY[d.group] = h / (Math.random() * (d.group.length - 0 + 1) + 1);
                        
                        return inposY[d.group];
                    }
                }))
                .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-500))
                .force('center', d3.forceCenter(w / 2, h / 2))
                .force("gravity", d3.forceManyBody(50));

            linkElements = g.append('g').attr('class', 'links').selectAll('path').data(net.links).enter().append('path')
                .attr('class', function (d) { return 'link ' + d.type; })
                

            nodeElements = g.append('g').attr('class', 'nodes').selectAll('.node')
                .data(net.nodes)
                .enter().append('g')
                .attr('class', 'node');
            // .append('circle')
            // .attr("r", cRadius)
            // .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(d.group);});
            circle = nodeElements.filter(function (d) { return d.type == 'resource'; }).append('circle')
                .attr('class', 'circle')
                .attr("r", function (d) { return d.size; })
                .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.group); });

            nodeElements.call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragstarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragended));

            textElements = g.append("g")
                .attr("class", "texts")
                .selectAll("text")
                .data(net.nodes)
                .enter().append('text')
                .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                .attr('alignment-baseline', 'middle')
                .append('tspan')
                .text(function (node) { return node.label });

            simulation.nodes(net.nodes).on('tick', () => {
                genCH = convexHull.selectAll("path")
                    .data(groups)
                    .attr("d", groupPath)
                    .enter().insert("path", "circle")
                    .style("fill", groupFill)
                    .style("stroke", groupFill)
                    .style("stroke-width", 140)
                    .style("stroke-linejoin", "round")
                    .style("opacity", .5)
                    .on('click', function (evt, d) {
                        expand[d.key] = false;
                        init();
                    })
                    .attr("d", groupPath);

                nodeElements
                    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
                // .attr('x', function (node) { console.log(node); return node.x })
                // .attr('y', function (node) { return node.y })
                textElements
                    .attr('x', function (node) { return node.x })
                    .attr('y', function (node) { return node.y })
                linkElements
                    .attr('d', function (d) {
                        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
                            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                    

                        var val = 'M' + d.source.x + ',' + d.source.y + 'A' + (dr - drSub) + ',' + (dr - drSub) + ' 0 0,1 ' + d.target.x + ',' + d.target.y;

                        var val2 = 'M' + d.source.x + ',' + d.source.y + 'L' + (d.target.x) + ',' + (d.target.y);
                        if (d.type == 'resource') return val2;
                        else return val1;
                    });
            })

            nodeElements.on("mouseover", function (d) {
                set_highlight(d);
            })
                .on("mousedown", function (event, d) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    focus_node = d;
                
                    set_focus(d)
                    if (highlight_node === null) set_highlight(d)

                }).on("mouseout", function (event, d) {
                    exit_highlight();

                }).on("click", function (event, d) {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                
                    setExpand(d);
                });

            simulation.force("link").links(net.links).distance(function (d) {
                if (d.source.group == d.target.group) return 85;
                else return 180;
                // if(d.type=='resource') return 300;
                // else return 150;
                // return d.distance;
            });

            function setExpand(d) {
                expand[d.id] = !expand[d.id];
                init();
            }

            function exit_highlight() {
                highlight_node = null;
                if (focus_node === null) {
                    svg.style("cursor", "move");
                    if (highlight_color != "white") {
                        circle.style(towhite, "white");
                        linkElements.style("stroke", function (o) { return (isNumber(o.score) && o.score >= 0) ? color(o.score) : default_link_color });
                    }

                }
            }

            function set_focus(d) {
                if (highlight_trans < 1) {
                    circle.style("opacity", function (o) {
                        return isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : highlight_trans;
                    });

                    linkElements.style("opacity", function (o) {
                        return o.source.index == d.index || o.target.index == d.index ? 1 : highlight_trans;
                    });
                }
            }

            function set_highlight(d) {

                svg.style("cursor", "pointer");
                // circle.style('opacity',0.7);
                if (focus_node !== null) d = focus_node;
                highlight_node = d;

                if (highlight_color != "white") {
                    circle.style(towhite, function (o) {
                        return isConnected(d, o) ? highlight_color : "white";
                    });
                    //             linkElements.style("stroke", function(o) {
                    //            return o.source.index == d.index || o.target.index == d.index ? highlight_color : ((isNumber(o.score) && o.score>=0)?color(o.score):default_link_color);
                    // });
                }
            }

            function dragstarted(event, d) {
                if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
                d.fx = d.x;
                d.fy = d.y;
            }

            function dragged(event, d) {
                d.fx = event.x;
                d.fy = event.y;
            }

            function dragended(event, d) {
                if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
                d.fx = null;
                d.fy = null;
            }
            // endof init()
        }

        init();
        //add zoom capabilities
        var zoom_handler = d3.zoom()
            .on("zoom", zoom_actions);

        zoom_handler(svg);
        function zoom_actions(event) {
            g.attr("transform", event.transform);
        }

        function isNumber(n) {
            return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Robin, the d3.nest to d3.groups adaption killed me. This is helping me a lot. Do you also know why the click-expand function isn´t working in V6 any longer? In the v4 example it is possible to group the inner nodes. I will test it too.

Comment: Oooh I didn't notice the click-expand thing... I will have a look...

Comment: @ICoded - see my edit; I missed the `event` argument in the handler for `simulation.nodes...` in the `init` function. The expand/ collapse feature on the hulls is working now in the v6 port. HTH. Robin